# Multivariable function using two list

Tags: list, function, variables, plot, wolfram-mathematica

In mathematica

I  have a function it uses two list of values. the shape of x and y list gives a triangle.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MIBi.png)

xlist={-1., -0.447214, 0.447214, 1., -1., -0.333333, 0.447214, -1.,-0.447214, -1.}

ylist={-1., -1., -1., -1., -0.447214, -0.333333, -0.447214, 0.447214,0.447214, 1.}

function f=(1 + 2x + 5) (3 + 5 y)

I want to plot function in 3d with xlist on x axis ylist in y axis and see the funtion using this values in plot

I usually plot with x and y "min max range" with function, it gives a rectangle domain style shape as expected.

In this plot it will seem like a triangle bended carpet shape

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5oT7.png)

Thanks a lot regards

I usually plot with x and y "min max range" with function, it gives a rectangle domain style shape as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
xlist={-1.,-0.447214,0.447214,1.,-1.,-0.333333,0.447214,-1.,-0.447214,-1.};
ylist={-1.,-1.,-1.,-1.,-0.447214,-0.333333,-0.447214,0.447214,0.447214,1.};
f[{x_,y_}]:={x,y,(1+2x+5)(3+5y)};
xyz=Map[f,Transpose[{xlist,ylist}]];
ListPointPlot3D[xyz]
```

Once that displays you can put your mouse anywhere in the graph and press and hold the left mouse button and drag the mouse. That is sometimes a little difficult to decide exactly where to put the mouse and what direction to drag, but it will rotate the graph and you can try to see if the graph is correctly positioning your points in 3-d.  I notice that all your points line up, except for one of them. Is that perhaps an error or did you intend to have one of the points out of line with all the rest?

Or perhaps I misunderstood what you are asking for.

Try this plot and see if it is closer to what you want.

```
Plot3D[If[y < -x,(1+2x+5)(3+5y)],{x,-1,1},{y,-1,1}]
```

If this still isn't right then try to explain what I'm missing.

Comment: Thanks Bill, works great,
ListPlot3D[xyz] also worked for me to see a colored surface instead of seeing nodes 
Regards,